# ASP.NET Core apply Resource Filter to a folder

Tags: asp.net-core

```
   services.AddMvc(o => {
                o.Filters.Add(typeof(BoolResourceFilter));
            })
```

I have registered a resource filter globally but my app is separated in FrontEnd and BackOffice.

I would like to apply this filter to the FrontEnd Folder and all the razor pages or controllers inside it.

Is there a way to do this or i have to manually do on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a filter for controllers in 3 places:

- an action method
- a controller
- or globally

So if you want to apply them semi-globally, your best chance is to create or use an existing base controller class, apply your filter to it and then let all controllers from your "FrontOffice" inherit from it.

```
[CustomFilter("Foo")]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
}
```

Filters for Razor Pages on the other hand can very well be applied on a sub-folder basis:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
       .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
       {
           options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention(
               "/FrontOffice",
               model => model.Filters.Add(new CustomFiler("Foo")));
       });
}
```